# visual studio fonts and colors code snippet

Tags: fonts, colors, ide, code-snippets

I am struggling with setting fonts and colors manually.
I am trying to figure out how to set the background color of the Code Snippet when I create a property (type "prop", press [tab]).

I have tried adjusting most of the settings, but just cannot find it. I have checked through the Resharper ones as well as the regular ones.

I am using Visual Studio 2012 and Resharper 7.1.2

Turns out I cannot post images, but just believe me the background and foreground are very close in color.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the Background color of those items by changing your *Selected Text* color in Visual Studio Font & Color Settings.